# Append content via multiple CSS :after classes

Tags: css

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="required">required only</div>
<div class="note">note only</div>
<div class="required note">required and note</div>
<div class="note required">note and required</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.required:after { content: " *"; color: red; }
.note:after { content: " +"; color: red; }
```

The result in Firefox 11 is:

```
required only *
note only +
required and note +
note and required +
```

Where more than one class is supplied (.required and .note) I would like to have both "*" and "+" appended to the element such that:

```
required and note *+
note and required +*
```

Is this possible using pure CSS, and if so, how?

Edit: Here's a link to jsfiddle for this example: http://jsfiddle.net/xpZST/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need additional rules for this to work.

Given that the ordering of classes matters (when normally it shouldn't!), you'll need to use attribute selectors instead of class selectors, and you'll need to create *two* rules:

```
[class="required note"]:after { content: " *+"; color: red; }
[class="note required"]:after { content: " +*"; color: red; }
```

Simply add these rules after the ones you have and it should work, as attribute and class selectors are equally specific.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xpZST/1)

By the way, if you have common styles you can keep your code DRY by isolating them in another rule. For example, you can select each class and give them both `color: red`:

```
.required:after, .note:after { color: red; }
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xpZST/2)

Comment: Thank very much, this is what I was looking for. Assuming order did not matter, would each permutation of .class:after have to be expressed with its own rule?

Comment: @loopforever: Nope; you can choose to use either `.required.note:after` or `.note.required:after`, and it'll work for both permutations.